# How can I publish my PWA to the App Store?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA (built with C #) 100% working and running on the Play Store, but I would like to put this same PWA on the App Store (Iphone) How can I compile the project on my macOS system to publish it on the App Store?

Comment: Well, you need *some* framework or tool that will compile a valid iOS app from a "PWA". We're not here to recommend any such tools to you.

Comment: I believe that at the moment this isn’t possible.